# How to extract several observations of another dataframe and include it in the main dataframe under conditions?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I am working with two different dataframes that both include different observations of a categorical variable and its frequency in a specific year, but for two different groups of different size (group 2 is bigger than group 1).

Now, I would like to include the frequency of those observations of group 2 in group 1 that have the same "value" for the categorical variable (a) and that are of the same year. So far, I was not able to find the correct function or for loop.

What I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)

    year_1 <- c(1914, 1915, 1916, 1917)
    a_1 <- c("blue", "green", "green", "blue")
    df_1 <- data.frame(a_1, year_1)
    df_1 <- group_by(a_1, year_1) %>% count(name = "counts") %>% 
            ungroup(a_1, year_1) %>% 
    df_1 <- mutate(freq_1=counts/sum(counts))

    year_2 <- c(1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918)
    a_2    <- c("black", "pink", "blue", "green", "green", "pink", "blue")
    df_2 <- data.frame(a_2, year_2)
    df_2 <- group_by(a_2, year_2) %>% count(name = "counts") %>% 
            ungroup(a_2, year_2) %>% 
    df_2 <- mutate(freq_2=counts/sum(counts))



    for(i in df_1) {
      if(df_2$a_2==df_1$a_1[i] & df_2$year_2==df_1$year_1[i]) {
       df_1 %>% 
       mutate(df_1, freq_2 = df_2$freq_2) %>% 
        return(df_1)}

      }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: does one of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

#just recreating your data with minor corrections
year_1 <- c(1914, 1915, 1916, 1917)
a_1 <- c("blue", "green", "green", "blue")
df_1 <- data.frame(a_1, year_1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_1 <- df_1 %>% group_by(a_1, year_1) %>% tally() %>% 
        ungroup(a_1, year_1) %>% 
        mutate(freq_1=n/sum(n))

year_2 <- c(1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918)
a_2    <- c("black", "pink", "blue", "green", "green", "pink", "blue")
df_2 <- data.frame(a_2, year_2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_2 <- df_2 %>% group_by(a_2, year_2) %>% tally() %>% 
        ungroup(a_2, year_2) %>% 
        mutate(freq_2=n/sum(n))


df_1 %>% left_join(df_2, by = c("year_1" = "year_2", "a_1" = "a_2")) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(!is.na(n.y), n.x + n.y, n.x),
         freq = count/sum(count)) %>% select(-n.y, -n.x, - freq_1, -freq_2 )

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  a_1   year_1 count  freq
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 blue    1914     2 0.286
2 blue    1917     1 0.143
3 green   1915     2 0.286
4 green   1916     2 0.286
```

This adds all categories from `df_2` to `df_1` which exist in the same year in both data frames, adds up their respective frequencies from both data frames and calculates a new percentage analogous to your `freq_1`and `freq_2`-columns.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. However, I don't need a newly calculated frequency. Therefore, I just use the left_join command.

Comment: glad to help. If you think the answer might help other people with a similar problem like yours, you can accept the answer and/or upvote, so others know immediatly what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with [aggregate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/aggregate) and [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/merge) or with [ave](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/ave):

```
#Your original Data
df1 <- data.frame(a=c("blue", "green", "green", "blue"), year=c(1914, 1915, 1916, 1917))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c("black", "pink", "blue", "green", "green", "pink", "blue"), year=c(1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918))

#Count per a and year
df1 <- with(df1, aggregate(list(count=year), list(a=a, year=year), FUN=length))
df2 <- with(df2, aggregate(list(count=year), list(a=a, year=year), FUN=length))

#Include counts of df2 in df1 using aggregate and merge
merge(df1[c("a","year")], aggregate(count ~ a + year, data=rbind(df1, df2), FUN=sum))
      a year count
1  blue 1914     2
2  blue 1917     1
3 green 1915     2
4 green 1916     2

#Include counts of df2 in df1 using ave
df1$count <- with(rbind(df1, df2), ave(count, a, year, FUN=sum))[1:NROW(df1)]
df1
      a year count
1  blue 1914     2
2 green 1915     2
3 green 1916     2
4  blue 1917     1
```